# How can I run a function until it meets the desired outcome?

Tags: javascript

Consider this code. It is a gross simplification of the program I am writing.

```
let numberOne;
let numberTwo;

function assignNumbers() {
  numberOne = Math.random()*10
  numberTwo = Math.random()*10
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run the `assignNumbers()`function until both `numberOne` and `numberTwo` are less than `5`. Here's what I've come up with, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path:

```
if (numberOne < 5 && numberTwo < 5) {
    console.log('success');
    return;
  } else {
    //what goes in here?
  }
```

Of course, I could put `assignNumbers()` in the `else` block, but it could fail again. How do I ensure that `assignNumbers()` runs until both `numberOne` and `NumberTwo` are less than 5?

Comment: See [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just providing a one-liner:

```
do assignNumbers(); while (numberOne > 4 && numberTwo > 4);
```

Then you know both `numberOne` and `numberTwo` have the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this either using loops or recursively (as said by [Ashay Mandwarya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6766919/ashay-mandwarya))

```js
// Using Loops

let numberOne;
let numberTwo;

function assignNumbers() {
  numberOne = Math.random()*10;
  numberTwo = Math.random()*10;
}

while(true){
  assignNumbers();
  if(numberOne < 5 && numberTwo < 5){
    console.log(numberOne + ' ' + numberTwo);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to call it again if the number are greater than 5.
It checks if both the numbers are less than 5. If yes it returns the number else it calls the function again

```js
let numberOne;
let numberTwo;

function assignNumbers() {
  numberOne = Math.random()*10
  numberTwo = Math.random()*10
  if(numberOne<5 && numberTwo<5)
  return numberOne+ " " +numberTwo
  else
  return assignNumbers()
}
console.log(assignNumbers())
```

Comment: StackOverflow? :)

Comment: @AndrewShmig ***Technically*** ES6 has tail-call optimization but trusting the engine to do it is a true source of bugs

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using **recursion** with ES6 arrow functions and ternary operators

```
let numberOne;
let numberTwo;

const assignNumbers = () => {
   numberOne = Math.random()*10
   numberTwo = Math.random()*10
   return (numberOne < 5 && numberTwo < 5) ? `${numberOne} ${numberTwo}` : assignNumbers();
}
console.log(assignNumbers())
```